# OSX G++ Application Icon

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++

I am trying to set an application icon for a C++ Mac Application compiled with G++. I made an Info.plist file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>foo.icns</string>
</dict>
```

I then compile it like so:

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo Info.plist
```

And it returns:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file Info.plist, file was built for unsupported file format
( 0x3C 0x3F 0x78 0x6D 0x6C 0x20 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x3D 0x22 0x31 )
which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): Info.plist
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Hmm try cleaning or restarting xcode. It can be buggy at times.

Comment: I am not using xcode. Only plain C++ and GCC to compile it.

Comment: I see. What does your make file look like?

Comment: I don't have a make file for it. Should I have one?

Comment: Yes I would recommend making one how else would it compile the info.plist?